# Converting to real 8bpp Jpeg

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I already searched and tried all the suggestions given it at SO, AForge, FreeImage and couple more websites, but I'm unable to transform an image into a real 8bpp one. I always get the JPEG saved as 24bpp instead of 8.

After the grayscale conversion I have a MemoryBMP (according to myImage.RawFormat), so when I save it like this

```
myImage.Save("image.jpg");
```

I get a 3Mb+ image (so I assume it's saved in BMP) which Windows tells me is 8bpp (but I need it to be JPEG). But if I save it like this

```
myImage.Save("image_JPEG.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I get a 400Kb image (so I assume it's saved in JPEG) but it's in 24bpp.

Any ideas what can be causing this?

**EDIT**

As JYelton mentioned this is a limitation of Image.Save() method, so I changed to saving the image with the FreeImage library: FreeImage.SaveBitmap() works like a charm.

Comment: Why do you need the JPG to be 8-bit? FYI, some people seem to refer to an image where each channel (R, G, B) has 8 bits as an "8-bit JPG". If that's what you're after, then I think you have it. 8 bits per channel yields 24-bit color.

Comment: The default image format for the Image.Save(string) overload is PNG, not BMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The `Image.Save()` method does **not** support 8 bit per pixel for JPEG format. You may want to use the [FreeImage library](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) instead, as mentioned in the comments below.

---

If you want to reduce color depth to 8 bits per pixel, typically that is the same as converting from 24-bit color to grayscale, where each color channel has 8 bits per pixel to begin with. (In other words, reducing 3 channels of color information to 1.)

The default encoder when using `Image.Save()` and specifying `ImageFormat.Jpeg` is 24 bpp, so you'll need to specify an encoder and supply some parameters:

```
ImageCodecInfo[] availableCodecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
ImageCodecInfo jpgCodec = availableCodecs.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.MimeType == "image/jpeg");
if (jpgCodec == null)
    throw new NotSupportedException("Encoder for JPEG not found.");

EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 8L);

myImage.Save("image_JPEG.jpg", jpgCodec, encoderParams);
```

This is a modified example from a longer explanation I found at [aspnet-answers.com](http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/Csharp/35481316/how-to-save-an-8bit-grayscale-jpeg-image.aspx).

Comment: Tried using EncoderParameters but it didn't made any difference. Made 2 saves: myImage.Save("image_JPEG.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); and myImage.Save("image_JPEG.jpg", jpgCodec, encoderParams);, and afet did a binary file comparison and both file were exactly the same.

Comment: Just tried EncoderParameters to specify the ColorDepth for TIFF format and it works correctly but it has no difference in Jpeg.

Comment: A related question has [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479130/converting-8-bit-grayscale-tiff-image-to-8-bit-grayscale-jpg-in-net-2-0#comment20529430_14679450) indicating that 8bpp is not supported by Image.Save, which I was unaware of. It will require some more investigating.

Comment: Also of interest, here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4050751/161052) claiming that JPEG doesn't support less than three 8-bit channels. I know I've created grayscale jpegs using Adobe Photoshop, and they are definitely only 1-channel 8bpp, so that seems to be a false claim. Perhaps it is a limitation of the .NET support.

Comment: As you mentioned, it's a limitation of the Image.Save() method. So I changed to saving the image with the FreeImage library. Thanks for the pointers ;)

Comment: @Gonçalo Cardoso Is the answer valid or not? Accepting an answer and then saying in the comments that it does not work is not helpful.

Comment: @Ecnerwal did you see my edit (from 22/07/2014) on the original post? "As JYelton mentioned this is a limitation of Image.Save() method, so I changed to saving the image with the FreeImage library: FreeImage.SaveBitmap() works like a charm."

Comment: The answer is still accepted for no reason. Some people might look at the title and at the answer and then try to implement it as it and they will waste their time. The good way would have been to have another answer and mark it as accepted. not accept an answer where the real answer is in the comments....

Comment: @Ecnerwal I updated the answer to reflect the Image.Save() limitation with 8bpp JPEG format and suggested the OP's solution per comments. Perhaps now this item will not bother you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to verify if `ImageFormat.Jpeg` supports `Encoder.ColorDepth`:

```cs
using System.Linq;
bool IsSupportedParameters(ImageFormat imageFormat, Encoder encoder)
{
    var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(c => c.FormatID == imageFormat.Guid);

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    EncoderParameters? paramList = bitmap.GetEncoderParameterList(codec.Clsid);
    if (paramList != null)
    {
        return paramList.Param.Any(encParams => encParams.Encoder.Guid == encoder.Guid);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Lead to:

```cs
IsSupportedParameters(ImageFormat.Jpeg, Encoder.ColorDepth); // false
IsSupportedParameters(ImageFormat.Jpeg, Encoder.ChrominanceTable); // true
```

So you need to use another library to achieve what you want. For example see:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31962503/136285

References:

- [How to: Determine the Parameters Supported by an Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-determine-the-parameters-supported-by-an-encoder)
- [Encoder.ColorDepth Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.colordepth)