# Save .jpg image in grayscale using C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, jpeg, grayscale

I'm trying to save a Bitmap to jpg gray scale (8-bits) file, but when I try to use save method passing filename, ImageCodecInfo and EncoderParameters it saves an image in grayscale but in 24-bits, below follow my code:

```
using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(f.FullName))
{
    //ImageProcessor.CopyToBpp(b, 8) convert image from color to 8-bits grayscale
    using (Bitmap img = bitPixel == 8 ? ImageProcessor.CopyToBpp(b, 8) : (Bitmap)b.Clone())
    {
        /*
            * Here my img variable is a image in 8-bit (img.PixelFormat == Format8bppIndexed)
            * */

        string path = Path.Combine(pathToSave, string.Concat(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.FullName), ".jpg"));
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)smoothing);

        img.Save(path, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);

        img.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Even I trying to force a EncoderParameter to set ColorDepth passing the value 8L (8 long) it still saving the file in 24-bits.

Are there a way to save jpg gray scale using C# or I have to use some C++ component?

Comment: The answer in this post seems to say that it is a limation of Image.Save

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871466/converting-to-real-8bpp-jpeg

Comment: 8 BPP is not grayscale, it is an indexed color; totally unrelated. GDI+ does not support indexed colors for JPEGs.